# Explain about the redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is method in the users_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Here the code

```
redirect_to @user
```

automatically redirect to the show action, can anybody explain it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You succesfully created a User. As a result, you are redirected to the user you just created through it's newly created id. Redirect_to means you are redirecting to an other action, in this case the show action. In other words, you are no longer using @user from your create action, but @user from your show action (User.find(params[:id]). If you would change the redirect_to @user to redirect_to @users you would be redirected to the index action of user upon succesfull creation.

If you would like a bit more detail: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

For example:

> "Unlike index, the create action will not render a template. After performing its main purpose (creating a new post), it initiates a redirect instead. This redirect works by returning an external “302 Moved” HTTP response that takes the user to the show or index action, depending on the redirect."